# How can I print the longest sequence of lines featuring numbers smaller than a threshold?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I am learning Perl, but I don't know how to solve this problem.

I have a `.txt` file of the following form:

```
1 16.3346384
2 11.43483
3 1.19819
4 1.1113829
5 1.0953443
6 1.9458343
7 1.345645
8 1.3847385794
9 1.3534344
10 2.1117454
11 1.17465
12 1.4587485
```

The first column only contains the line number, which is not of interest here, but it is present in the file; the values in the second column are the relevant part.

I want to output the longest contiguous sequence of lines which feature numbers smaller than 2.00 in the second column. For the above example, this would be lines 3 to 9 , and the output should be:

```
1.19819
1.1113829
1.0953443
1.9458343
1.345645
1.3847385794
1.3534344
```

Comment: Never apologize for not speaking _a foreign language_ perfectly! It is hard, and you are trying, and that is all anyone can ask!

Comment: What if there's a tie (equal longest contiguous sequence of lines satisfying the criteria)? Do you want the first such sequence, the last such sequence, or something else?

Comment: tie is 14 and 14, e.g.? I need one longest, first found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not quite a trivial task. There is also debate whether providing a finished program is helpful for others learning to solve a problem in a programming language, but I believe it has its merits, so I propose the following program (let's call it `findlongestsequence.pl`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my $limit; my $infile;
GetOptions( 'limit=f' => \$limit, 'infile=s' => \$infile );

my $lineno=0; my $groupstart;
my $currlength=0; my $maxlength=0; my $ingroup=0;
my @columns; my @groupbuf; my @longestgroup;

if (! open(fileinput, '<', "$infile" )) {exit 1;};
while (<fileinput>)
{
    $lineno++;
    @columns = split(/\s+/,$_);

    if ( $ingroup == 0 && $columns[1]<$limit )
    {
        $ingroup=1;
        $groupstart=$lineno;
        @groupbuf=();
    }

    if ( $ingroup == 1 )
    {
        if ($columns[1]>=$limit )
        {
            $ingroup=0;
            $currlength=$lineno-$groupstart;
    
            if ( $currlength>$maxlength )
            {
                $maxlength=$currlength;
                @longestgroup=@groupbuf;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            push(@groupbuf,$columns[1]);
        }
    }
}
close(fileinput);

if ( $ingroup == 1 )
{
    $currlength=$groupstart-$lineno;
    if ( $currlength>$maxlength )
    {
        $maxlength=$currlength;
        @longestgroup=@groupbuf;
    }
}

print join("\n",@longestgroup),"\n";
exit 0;
```

You can call the program as

```shell
./findlongestsequence.pl --infile input.txt --limit 2.0
```

This will first interpret the command-line parameters using `Getopt::Long`.

It will then open the file and read it line-wise while, and keep a line-counter in `$lineno`. Every line will be split into columns at whitespace.

- If the program is not inside a group of lines with values < `$limit` (`$ingroup` is zero), but encounters a suitable line, it will record that it is now in such a group (`$ingroup` set to one), store the group start in `$groupstart` and start buffering the column 2 values in an array `@groupbuf`.
- If the program is inside such a group, but the current value is larger than the `$limit`, it will recognize the end-of-group and calculate its length. If this is longer than the previously recorded longest group, the content (`@groupbuf`) and length (`$currlength`) of the new longest group is copied to `@longestgroup` and `$maxlength`, respectively.

Since it is possible that a group is terminated by end-of-file rather than a line with value > `$limit`, perform this check also if `$ingroup` is true at end-of-file.

At the end, the content of `@longestgroup` is printed with `\n` as token separator.

Comment: Hmmm, without regex... Very interesting

Comment: @694201970 Well, if you look at the `split` call, there is one regex (albeit only to specify where to split into columns) ;)

Comment: i wanna use this  ^(?:1\.\d{2}|[0-1]\.\d{2,20}|2\.00-)$

Comment: @694201970 I understand you want to use regex, and I can give you an answer based on regex, but maybe it's better you try to explain what would you expect your regex to work. Why `?:1` at the beginning? Why `-` at the end? Try to explain, and then we could tell you where you had you mistake. Also try to show this inside your own perl code.

Answer (score 5):

Perl one line:

```
perl -ne '$n = (split)[1]; if ($n > 2) {if ($i > $max) {$longest=$cur; $cur=""; $max=$i}; $i=0} else {$cur .= $n . "\n"; $i++} END {print $i > $max ? $cur : $longest}' < file.txt
```

Multi line for better readability:

```
perl -ne '
  $n = (split)[1];
  if ($n > 2) {
    if ($i > $max) {
      $longest=$cur;
      $cur="";
      $max=$i;
     }
     $i=0
  } else {
    $cur.= $n . "\n";
    $i++
  } 
  END {
    print $i > $max ? $cur : $longest
  }' < file.txt
```

One liner with `awk`:

```
awk '$2 > 2 { if (i > max) {res=cur; cur=""; max=i} i=0} $2 < 2 {cur = cur $2 "\n"; i++} END {if (i > max) res=cur; printf res}' file.txt
```

Multi line:

```
awk '
  $2 > 2 { 
    if (i > max) {
      res=cur
      cur=""
      max=i
    }
    i=0
  } 
  $2 < 2 {
    cur = cur $2 "\n"
    i++
  }
  END {
    if (i > max) res=cur
    printf res
  }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$2 >= 2 {
    max = getMax(cur,max)
    cur = ""
    next
}
{ cur = cur $2 ORS }
END {
    printf "%s", getMax(cur,max)
}
function getMax(a,b) {
    return ( gsub(ORS,"&",a) > gsub(ORS,"&",b) ? a : b )
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1.19819
1.1113829
1.0953443
1.9458343
1.345645
1.3847385794
1.3534344
```

Comment: yea, it works, but i see in output 12.022760651465799 between 1.xxxxx and 1.xxxxx

Comment: That's impossible since 12.022760651465799 isn't present in the input. Given the input you provided in your question for us to test with, my script produces the expected output you provided for us to test with, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
<input perl -snle '
  if ($_ < $limit) {
    $n++;
  } else {
    $max = $n if $n > $max;
    $n = 0;
  }
  END {
    print ($n > $max ? $n : $max);
  }' -- -limit=2 -max=0
```

Or if instead of the number of lines in that largest group of lines you want to see those lines as per newer edits to your question:

```
<input perl -snle '
  if ($_ < $limit) {
    push @lines, $_;
  } else {
    @max = @lines if @lines > @max;
    @lines = ();
  }
  END {
    print for @lines > @max ? @lines : @max;
  }' -- -limit=2
```

If, as someone edited in your question, the line numbers are part of the data, add the `-a` option (awk mode where records are split into the `@F` array) and replace `$_` (the whole record) with `$F[1]` (the second field, `$F[0]` being the first).

Comment: nope, just print 114035 (count string in a file)

Comment: @694201970 I just realised the fist number in the lines of the sample in your question was not part of the data. See edit

Comment: Even though your post doesn't answer the question, your original answer (before the edit) was actually better (in terms of what you were attempting to answer) than the current answer. Before the edit you were just missing the `-n` for the loop. Now it just takes the entire line without any splitting.

Comment: @avriro, -a which I had before, implies -n. The OP indicates (not very clearly) that the line numbers are not part of the data

Comment: Oops, my `-n` comment was wrong. But anyway, the OP **does** say it's part of the data. In the original question he said he only wanted to check only the second column. Also now, after the edit: _"The first column only contains the line number, which is not of interest here, **but it is present in the file**"_

Comment: Oh, now I understand why your first solution didn't work for me without `-n`. The first time I tried it, I used an older version of Perl - 5.18.2. This was only added in version [v5.20.0](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5200delta#-F-now-implies-a-and-a-implies-n): _"-F now implies -a and -a implies -n"_. So for older versions `-n` was required to make it work.

Comment: @aviro That text was not in the original question and added by others long after I posted my answer. The regex attempt by the OP suggest the numbers make up the whole line.

Comment: And would explain why with my initial answer, the OP was getting all the lines of the input as the second field would be empty and therefore considered as less than 2. Thanks for the portability note. I tend to prefer specifying the full `-F, -lane`. I've only been recently made aware that it was superfluous, and hadn't realised that was a recent addition).

Comment: @aviro yes, I added that (the fact the the numbers are in the actual file) to the question after the OP confirmed it in a [now deleted comment](https://i.imgur.com/7UaC1P4.png).

Answer (score 1):

Idiomatic solution using `<>` for reading input and the flipflop operator.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/766081/how-to-print-the-longest-sequence-of-lines-featuring-numbers-smaller-than-a-thre
my $threshold = 2.00;
my ($section, $maxsection, $len, $maxlen);
my $flipflop;
while (<>) {
    # Remove leading line number
    s/^(\d+)\s+//;
    # Flip flop operator
    # https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2010/11/make-exclusive-flip-flop-operators/
    if ($flipflop = $_ <= $threshold .. $_ > $threshold) {
        if ($flipflop =~ /E0$/) {
            # End of section
            if (!defined($maxlen) || $len > $maxlen) {
                $maxsection = $section;
                $maxlen = $len;
            }
            $len = 0;
            $section = "";
        } else {
            $len++;
            $section .= $_;
        }
    }
}
# One last possible end of section
if ($flipflop && $len > $maxlen) {
    $maxsection = $section;
}
print $maxsection;
```

Comment: Nice solve too.

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my (@max,@tmp);  $_ .= words;  \
             if .[1]  < 2 { @tmp.push: .[1] };    \
             if .[1] !< 2 { @max = @tmp if @tmp.elems > @max.elems; @tmp = Empty };  \
             END @max.elems >= @tmp.elems ?? (.put for @max) !! (.put for @tmp);'  file
```

OR:

```
~$ raku -ne 'BEGIN my (@max,@tmp);  $_ .= words;  \
             when .[1]  < 2 { @tmp.push: .[1] };  \
             default { @max = @tmp if @tmp.elems > @max.elems; @tmp = Empty };  \
             END @max.elems >= @tmp.elems ?? (.put for @max) !! (.put for @tmp);'  file
```

Here are answers written in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Raku features [rational numbers](https://course.raku.org/essentials/numbers/rats/), if ever you need to maintain precision when performing simple math operations (e.g. `say 0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3;`).

- The first answer reads lines into `$_` using the `-ne` non-autoprinting linewise flags. Both a `@max` and `@tmp` array are declared. The line is broken on whitespace into `words` and `.=` saved back into `$_`. If (`if` statement) the `.[1]` second columm satisfies the criteria, the values is `push`ed onto the `@tmp` array. If not, the `@tmp` array overwrites the `@max` array if it has more `elems` (elements). Regardless, the `@tmp` array is `Empty` (emptied). At the `END` to make sure a final contiguous sequence is/isn't the longest, Raku's **Test** `??` **True** `!!` **False** ternary operator is used to out`put` the longest array.
- The second answer is similar to the first except `when` statements are used. In Raku once a `when` conditional is satisfied its associated block is executed and control reverts to the outer block, skipping any subsequent `when` or `default` statements. See reference below.

Sample Input:

```
1 16.3346384
2 11.43483
3 1.19819
4 1.1113829
5 1.0953443
6 1.9458343
7 1.345645
8 1.3847385794
9 1.3534344
10 2.1117454
11 1.17465
12 1.4587485
```

Sample Output:

```
1.19819
1.1113829
1.0953443
1.9458343
1.345645
1.3847385794
1.3534344
```

---

*NOTE: The code above will output the **first** longest contiguous sequence in the case of a tie.*

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/when
https://docs.raku.org/
https://raku.org

Answer (score -2):

If you do not want to over-engineer, try this command line one-liner:

```
awk '{print $2}' yourfile.txt | sort -g > youroutput.txt
```

2. The first command will pick the second column of your file
3. The second command will sort the selected column based on general numeric sort and write into the output file.
   For more details and fiddling, check the man pages of `awk` and `sort`.

Comment: This doesn't print the longest sequence of lines whose second field is less than two, it simply prints al the values of the second field but sorted. This isn't what the question asks for.

Comment: Ah you're right! I've obviously misread here.